# Can I ask if a specific game will run on a specific computer system?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I want to ask if the Penumbra series will run on a playable and consistent framerate on a medium to high setting (this you can't assume from minimum system requirements) on a AMD A4 apu processor.

This is considering I don't have a computer to play the game with.

One thing about the demos is that they don't offer enough content to experience the true quantity of models and lighting effects throughout the full game.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One problem with this sort of question is that if we allow them, we'll get thousands of them.  There are tons of games and tons of computer configurations.  We can't possibly host a question for each combination, much less answer them all, much less answer them all *well*.

The obvious solution is to make it more general; something like [How can I check if my computer's powerful enough to run a certain game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/517/how-can-i-check-if-my-machine-will-be-able-to-run-a-game)

Now you might think it's different since you don't have the computer, but not really.  Can You Run It just compares the specs of your computer to the minimum/recommended specs for the game.  You can easily do that yourself; look at the game page in Steam, or on the box, or just do a web search for the specs of the game.

If that's still not good enough and you're interested more in someone's experience running the game, you run into some other problems:

- We still probably won't have someone who's run the game with your exact hardware
- Your question will probably be useful only to you, or to a tiny number of people looking at the same hardware and game
- The question may also be too localized in time; in a year or so, it's unlikely that anyone will be buying the same hardware you are now
- Stack Exchange sites are a place for gathering expertise.  Answering this question doesn't require any expertise; you only need to have the game and the hardware and to have seen how it runs.

SE isn't a good place for such localized questions, and people are likely to view it as uninteresting.  Who wants to dig up the specs for someone else's game/computer?  It's easy enough to learn how to estimate what the specs of a computer will let you do, so that's what I advise you to do.

Comment: Thanks matthew, this is certainly helpful.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.canyourunit.com exists.

Ergo, we don't need these questions, and, speaking for myself at least, don't want them. They are the convergence of shopping advice, general reference, and too localized.

Comment: But I'm not asking for shopping advice, I know what I want. I just want to know if what I want is powerful enough to play the games I have.

Comment: @Overmann Don't get hung up on semantics. Aside from shopping advice being one of *several* problems with this type of question, the oddities of your circumstance don't really address why these questions are a problem as a whole.

Comment: I read that URL as "Can Your Unit?", lol.

Answer (score 3):

This kind of question has been historically shut down with a "play a demo; not enough people have your hardware to make the question generally useful."

So... ask on chat... or go play the demo... or "arrange" one. :)

Comment: The demo for Peumbra is [here](http://www.penumbragame.com/demo.php).

Comment: The thing is I haven't bought the system yet, I wanted to know before buying.

Comment: I bought the game before buying a computer to play with it :P. I just had to have Penumbra.