# Is this question off topic?

Tags: support, site-policies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I ask if a specific game will run on a specific computer system?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3411/can-i-ask-if-a-specific-game-will-run-on-a-specific-computer-system)

If I were to list my system specs and ask if I could run Diablo III would that be bad?

I want to be good.

Good Boys Get Cookies.

Everyone Likes Cookies. :D

Comment: There _has_ been a public Diablo 3 beta... :)

Comment: @agent86 It would have been funnier if you closed this as off-topic ;)

Answer (score 2):

Don't list just your own system specifications and ask "Can I run it on this?". There's no real reason we need to field what is essentially the same question for every comp setup. We have a general question for this here: [How can I check if my computer's powerful enough to run a certain game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/517/how-can-i-check-if-my-machine-will-be-able-to-run-a-game)

We *do* have [system-requirements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-requirements), which is for questions about system requirements. A glance through it, though, shows that the questions are all "What are the system requirements", not "Does my machine meet these requirements". So you would assumedly want to go in *that* direction. This question is a primary example of that direction: [What are the system requirements for the Elder Scrolls: Skyrim?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30341/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-the-elder-scrolls-skyrim) - many others instead investigate specific elements of system requirements.

Comment: Also, questions pertaining to whether or not you can run it can be asked in our chat without fear of rep-loss or closure of said questions.